# Neutral Hydrogen Atom Time-Averaged Potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, notation, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm self-studying the 3rd edition of Jackson's *Classical Electrodynamics* and I have a question about a problem. The fifth problem of Chapter 1 asks the reader to determine the volume charge distribution giving rise to the potential

\begin{equation*}
\Phi = \frac{q}{4\pi \varepsilon_{0}}\frac{e^{-\alpha r}}{r}\left(1+\frac{\alpha r}{2}\right),
\end{equation*}

being the time-averaged potential of a neutral hydrogen atom and in which $\alpha = 2/\alpha_{0}$ with $\alpha_{0}$ being the Bohr radius.

I worked the problem, and found the answer

\begin{equation*}
\rho(r) = \frac{q}{4\pi r^{2}}\delta(r) - \frac{q\alpha^{3}e^{-\alpha r}}{8\pi}.
\end{equation*}

The [solutions manual I'm using](https://www.wtamu.edu/%7Ecbaird/all_homework_solutions/Jackson_1_5_Homework_Solution.pdf) (and also [this one](https://wpfiles.mines.edu/samizdat/jackson/main.pdf)), however, gives the answer as

\begin{equation*}
\rho(r) = q\delta(r) - \frac{q\alpha^{3}e^{-\alpha r}}{8\pi}.
\end{equation*}

It seems to me, though, that integration over all space shows that this distribution results in a total charge of $-q$, while the given potential is supposed to represent a *neutral* hydrogen atom. Also, it seems like the this potential has inconsistent units, $q\delta(r)$ having units of charge per length. I think my solution integrates to give a total charge of zero and has correct units. Does my solution look correct, or else am I misinterpreting the solutions manual?

Comment: "being to the time-averaged potential of a neutral hydrogen atom" the English isn't clear, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @lcv sorry, the "to" was a typo. I only meant that Jackson calls $\Phi$ "the time-averaged potential of a neutral hydrogen atom."

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my confusion came from a slight abuse of notation in the solutions manual. In fact, the charge density should read

\begin{equation*}
\rho(r) = q\delta(\mathbf{x})  - \frac{q\alpha^{3}e^{-\alpha r}}{8\pi},
\end{equation*}

that is, with $\delta(\mathbf{x})$ in place of $\delta(r)$. Since

\begin{equation*}
\delta(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{4\pi r^{2}}\delta(r)
\end{equation*}

in this case, both the answer in the solutions manual and my solution seem to be correct.

Answer (score -1):

Dr Baird's solutions are correct. But even the wrong one is less erroneous than yours. This is because all of us in the know are so used to the fact that
$$\tag1\phi=\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0r}\qquad\implies\qquad \rho=q\,\delta_3(r)$$
The way that this question is framed, however, should be attacked with a variant of the spherical Laplacian in the Poisson equation that looks like
$$
\begin{align}
\tag2\frac1r\partial_r^2(r\Phi)&=-\frac\rho{\varepsilon_0}\\
\tag3\frac1r\partial_r^2e^{-\alpha r}(1+\frac{\alpha r}2)&=-\frac{4\pi\rho}q\\
\tag4\frac1re^{-\alpha r}(\partial_r-\alpha)^2(1+\frac{\alpha r}2)&=-\frac{4\pi\rho}q\\
\tag5\rho&=-\frac{q\alpha^3e^{-\alpha r}}{8\pi}
\end  {align}
$$
but the above computation always discards the singularity at the origin; we have to remember to manually insert Equation (1), so that the solution is
$$\tag6\rho=q\left(\delta_3(r)-\frac{\alpha^3}{8\pi}e^{-\alpha r}\right)$$

Comment: So integrating this over all space, we obtain

\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\pi}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rho r^{2}\sin{(\theta)}\mathrm{d}r}\mathrm{d}\theta}\mathrm{d}\phi} = -\frac{q\alpha^{3}}{8\pi}\cdot 4\pi\cdot\int_{0}^{\infty}{r^{2}e^{-\alpha r}\mathrm{d}{r}} = -q
\end{equation*}

Is this integration incorrect?

Comment: That integration of yours is only capturing the electron part. The proton part is where the Dirac delta distribution contributes, and would have given you the $+q$, so that overall there is neutrality.

Comment: So is this much correct?

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\pi}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rho r^{2}\sin{(\theta)}\mathrm{d}r}\mathrm{d}\theta}\mathrm{d}\phi} &= \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\pi}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\left[q\delta(r) -\frac{q\alpha^{3}}{8\pi}e^{-\alpha r}\right]r^{2}\sin{(\theta)}\mathrm{d}r}\mathrm{d}\theta}\mathrm{d}\phi}\\
&= 4\pi q \int_{0}^{\infty}{\left[r^{2}\delta(r) - \frac{\alpha^{3}}{8\pi}r^{2}e^{-\alpha r}\right]\mathrm{d}{r}}
\end{align*}

Comment: That has many mistakes. You also need to note that I explicitly wrote $\delta_3$ because it is different from $\delta$. In particular $4\pi r^2\delta_3(r)=\delta(r)$

Comment: I don't know what mistakes it has, but I agree with your statement about the delta function in three dimensions in spherical coordinates. Therefore, $\delta_{3}(r) = \delta(r)/(4\pi r^{2})$, and $\triangle(1/r) = \delta_{3}(r)$. And using $\delta_{3}(r)$, my solution is the same as yours...